# Automate background color of nested elements with SASS functions

Tags: css, sass

I’m making a multi-level navigation system and want each level’s background color to darken by 20% (so 1st level = #fff, 2nd = #ccc, 3rd = #999 and so on). There has GOT to be an awesome way to dynamically automate this process using SASS functions but I can’t quite wrap my head around how the statement would be setup. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

[FIDDLE](http://sassmeister.com/gist/1ae366f4646f45381a4f)

```
<ul>
  <li>Level 1: Item 1 (#fff)
    <ul>
      <li>Level 2: Item 1 (#ccc)</li>
      <li>Level 2: Item 2 (#ccc)
        <ul>
          <li>Level 3: Item 1 (#999)</li>
          <li>Level 3: Item 2 (#999)</li>
          <li>Level 3: Item 3 (#999)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Level 2: Item 3 (#ccc)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Level 1: Item 2 (#fff)</li>
  <li>Level 1: Item 3 (#fff)</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
li
  background: darken(white, 20%)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save yourself a fair bit if work if you just take advantage of alpha transparency.

```
li li
  background: rgba(black, .2)
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/d329c946068d3075ba72

P.S. it also helps to have valid markup.

Comment: whoops good catch. the actual menu will be dynamically created... for this example seems I was a bit careless. original link updated. though this solution does produce a similar effect to what i'm going for, opacity isn't an option/colors need to be solid.

Comment: Unless your ul elements have a specified background as well, then setting the first list to solid white will do the job.

Comment: @cimmanon Nice, this is much more elegant than my answer, and I'd definitely advocate using it when possible.  One case where the more complex SASS approach would still be helpful is if you wanted to, say, use a *list* of colors for the different levels, instead of just darkening them the same amount each time; or if you wanted to do a non-linear scale, i.e., lighten($initial, someFunctionOfDepth()).

Comment: aHA! I had had that thought but applied it to the ul rather than the first li, so the transparency didn't stack/create the desired effect. that does the trick so even though the function provided by @anandthakker works as well and shed some light on using functions for me, i'm switching to accept this answer as i prefer the most simple/direct approach to things :) thanks all.

Answer (score 6):

A recursive mixin ought to do it:

```sass
@mixin levels($initial, $percentage, $depth)
  $next: darken($initial, $percentage)
  @if ($depth > 0)
    li
      background: $initial
      @include levels($next, $percentage, $depth - 1)

@include levels(white, 20%, 5)
```

Essentially, the `levels` mixin creates an `li` rule, but then nests another copy of `levels` within it. (And the `$depth` parameter makes sure it doesn't go on forever.)

You could mess around with the `li` selector for more control, e.g., change it to a `.class` selector, or use stuff like `& > ul > li`.