# Generate self include function in sass (recursive)

Tags: sass, styles

i have 10 deepth level elements. In every step (deepth) i want to make bigger padding. So first elements would be 0px another 20px another 40px ... etc. First selector it's simple, second must be under first one but it's exacly the same ... please look at code below which i want to get in sass:

```
  .folder-list-item {
    .padding-icon {
      padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .folder-list-item {
      .padding-icon {
        padding-left: 20px;
      }

      .folder-list-item {
        .padding-icon {
          padding-left: 40px;
        }

        .....

        .folder-list-item {
          .padding-icon {
            padding-left: n*20px;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can i create this in SASS (of course i don't want to create it by hand) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate background color of nested elements with SASS functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320442/automate-background-color-of-nested-elements-with-sass-functions)

Comment: You have right, that's duplicate. I didn't see this. How to delete it ?